# udp sendto can not send the whole txt file in a real time

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I have really strange problem. I made server and client communicating using unicast sockets.
Server is sending text file in blocks of 512 bytes and client is receiving and writing blocks to a txt file. But I noticed that without sleep(1) function on both sides server can not send the whole file. For example the file is made of 2939 blocks and in wireshark I can see just 1827, 2005, 1657 but never the whole file , all 2939 blocks ? Why ? Packets are not lost because server and client are connected via ethernet cable to the router and are on the same local network.

Can you give me directions and advices how to solve this problem? Here is the code :

```
#includes...
#define BUF_SIZE 512
#define PORT 1234
#define IP "192.168.0.103" // address of a client

static int val = 1;
int sent=0;

int main() {

    struct sockaddr_in client,server;
    char tmp[BUF_SIZE];
    int n,s,fd;
    ssize_t numRead;
    int rv,optval=1;

    if((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))<0){
        printf("Opening datagram socket error",strerror(errno));
        return 1;

    }else{
        printf("Opening datagram socket....OK.\n");
    }

    if(setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(optval)) == -1){ 
        printf("Setsockopt error: %s", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }


    memset((char *) &server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    memset((char *) &client, 0, sizeof(client));
    client.sin_family = AF_INET;
    client.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP); 
    client.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if(bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server))){
        printf("Binding datagram socket error %s",strerror(errno));
        close(s);
        return 1;

    }


   if((fd = open("udp_text.txt", O_RDONLY , 0777))== -1){
      printf("Error while opening txt file %s!\n",strerror(errno));
      return 1;

   }

    while (1) {
        if((numRead = read(fd,tmp,512)) == 512){ 
            tmp[numRead]='\0';
            rv = sendto(s,tmp,sizeof(tmp),0, (struct sockaddr *) &client, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

        memset(tmp,0,BUF_SIZE);

        }else{
        rv = sendto(s,tmp,sizeof(tmp),0, (struct sockaddr *) &client, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        printf("EOF !\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

close(s);
return 0;
}
```

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since not all the packets show up in wireshark, I would guess that the sender is running out of network packet buffer space in the operating system.  UDP can not only suffer packet loss from transmission failures but also if any routing component runs out of capacity and is forced to drop the packet because it is too busy.  This includes the local internet protocol stack.

As a start, check the error code from sendto().  If the local operating system is to blame then it will likely have the courtesy of reporting an error.

Update: No error from sendto(), well then, no easy fix.

One final note of caution/advice.  Even direct ethernet connections between hosts does not guarantee packets will always get through.  If you depend on the file data getting transferred reliably then you'll need to add some kind of acknowledgement response from the receiver to confirm successful reception of the data.  And associated logic in the sender to retransmit data as required.

That's a fair bit of work and why you might rather switch to TCP sockets which do all that for you.

Comment: Hi, sendto is always returning 1-No error, but still it can sent all the packets , what should I do?

Comment: Hi, I solved the problem by increasing buffer size #define BUF_SIZE 518. Thx !

Comment: Be careful.  There's no particular reason changing BUF_SIZE should fix the problem.  It is quite likely that in different circumstances the program will fail again.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this is happening then?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to send files over UDP, at least use an existing protocol that is designed for that purpose, like Trivial FTP (see [RFC 1350](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1350)). It offers buffer size control and safety from dropped packets.

Comment: Well, TFTP is UDP based but it has unicast communication, ACK based retransmission mechanism which is not suitable for me. Although it offers buffer size control it is hard to find how it is exactly implemented and how can I use their benefits.

Comment: The ACKs ensure the file blocks arrive correctly and in the right order. Your current code does neither of those. Remember that UDP in not reliable. See RFCs [2347](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2347) (TFTP Option Extension), [2348](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2348) (TFTP Blocksize Option), and [2349](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2349) (TFTP Timeout Interval and Transfer Size Options) for extra options you can control on the blocks.